# how can I convert normal string to json object in Powershell

Tags: json, powershell

I have this table in normal string format ,
[image]

I want to convert this string to json object in PowerShell. `ConvertTo-Json` is not giving in correct format.

Comment: Please share your code and the “incorrect format” results. Also show what you’re expecting to end up with.

Comment: What is the correct format?

Answer (score 2):

The answer depends somewhat on the true format of the table.  If I assume this is tab delimited and that each column name doesn't have spaces I could pull it out something like:

```
$String =
@"
test    test2   first   others  versions
------------------------------------------
Decimal 1       2       5       p
Decimal 1       3       8       p
Decimal 1       2       4       i
Decimal 2       2       6       p
Decimal 5       4       6       k
Decimal 2       5       2       p
"@


$String  = $String -split "\r?\n" 
$Headers = $String[0] -split "\s"

$Objects = 
$String[2..($String.Count -1)] |
ConvertFrom-Csv -Header $Headers -Delimiter "`t" |
ConvertTo-Json
```

Above, `-split` the big string into lines, then look at the header line and `-split` it to get an array of column headers. Now skipping the first 2 elements in the `$String` array convert the remaining lines to objects using `ConvertFrom-Csv` and using the previously extracted `$Headers` array.

Note: This segment may also work and may be preferred for readability:

```
$Objects = 
$String |
Select-Object -Skip 2 |
ConvertFrom-Csv -Header $Headers -Delimiter "`t" |
ConvertTo-Json
```

Note: Splitting on white space ( `"\s"` ) may cause issues if the field data may have whitespace itself.

However, given the ambiguity, a more certain approach might be more reliable, I would use the known start and end positions of the table's fields to do this.

Continuing with the above example string:

```
$String =
@"
test    test2   first   others  versions
------------------------------------------
Decimal 1       2       5       p
Decimal 1       3       8       p
Decimal 1       2       4       i
Decimal 2       2       6       p
Decimal 5       4       6       k
Decimal 2       5       2       p
"@

$String  = $String -Split "\r?\n" 

$String |
Select-Object -Skip 2 |
ForEach-Object{
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        test     = $_.SubString(0,7)
        test2    = $_.SubString(8,1)
        first    = $_.SubString(14,1)
        others   = $_.SubString(20,1)
        versions = $_.SubString(26,1)
    }
}
```

Again, these positions may change depending if the columns are separated by spaces or tabs. My sample data may not be the same as yours and you may need to play with those positions.  That said this is a very useful technique for deal with output from traditional console applications, very much worth knowing...

Note: Thanks Neko Nekoru; I added '?' to the RegEx to accommodate both Unix & Windows line ending styles.

Comment: Powershell does not always use `\r\n`, to bee foolproof change your split on the crlf to `\r?\n`